Mocking NextJS's useParams with Jest and RTL
As titled
I set up the following jest mock for next/navigation
jest.mock('next/navigation', async () => {
  const actual = await jest.requireActual('next/navigation');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...actual,
    useParams: jest.fn(),
    useRouter: jest.fn(() => ({
      push: jest.fn(),
      replace: jest.fn(),
    })),
    useSearchParams: jest.fn(),
    usePathname: jest.fn(),
  }
});

and then in my test block
describe('ChannelDetailPage', () => {

  const SomePage = () => (
    <SomeProvider value={mockProvider}>
      <SomeTemplate />
    </SomeProvider>
  );

  it('renders items correctly', async () => {
    const useParams = require('next/navigation').useParams;
    useParams.mockReturnValue({ slug: 'test-slug' });
    render(<SomePage />);

However the test failed with the following messages
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mockReturnValue')

      89 |   it('renders items correctly', async () => {
      90 |     const useParams = require('next/navigation').useParams;
    > 91 |     useParams.mockReturnValue({ slug: 'test-slug' });

Most of the docs related to this are for react-router-dom only, but this is useParams from NextJS's next/navigation, and the search results were very little.
Therefore i need help here to point and guide me of doing test with Jest RTL for NextJS's custom hooks.
